# How can I amend the last migration with Django module South?

Tags: django, migration, django-south

I've the following migrations:

- 0001_initia.py
- 0002_solve_null.py

After a `./manage.py migrate legacy --database=local_legacy` I realized I missed some modification that should belong to migration `0002`.

How can I amend it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting on an old question - hopefully better late than never.

You can amend/update a migration locally using the `--update` flag.

From [the south tutorial](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part3.html):

```
./manage.py schemamigration southtut --auto --update
```

This just rolls back the current migration, adds the new changes, and applies the updated version. Ashish Kasturia's answer is still right, this just makes it a little easier.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually delete the 0002 file and recreate the schema migration. A new 0002 file wil be created.

Just make sure the migration is re-runnable. For example, if you dropped a column in the previous 0002 file, you need to manually add the column back in the table. Or else, the next time you apple 0002 it will fail.

Or, you can create a new migration with the missing stuff.

Comment: should I _fake_ migrate to migration 0001 with prior to that?

Comment: As long as you're current till 0001 you should be okay. Just make sure 0002 is rerunnable.